# is there a command line terminal interface to git

Tags: centos, command-line, git

I am looking for an command line terminal based git client interface to git on centos linux.is it available?

Comment: Isnt' `git` itself what you're looking for? Or you want something like [this one](https://github.com/donnemartin/gitsome)?

Answer (score 3):

[`tig`](http://jonas.nitro.dk/tig/) perhaps? It’s very useful for exploring repositories, but it can also help prepare commits, merge files, cherry-pick commits...